# Meteor 1.9 build broken with rollup enabled

Tags: meteor, commonjs, angular-meteor, rollupjs, core-js

I'm getting following error in my Angular Meteor project:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE] [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes. Received '\u0000commonjs-proxy:/builds/intemp/in-pool/node_modules/core-js/internals/package.json'
     at readFile (fs.js:295:10)
     at go$readFile (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.9.0.1mtsmz6.qnno++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:110:14)
     at Object.readFile (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.9.0.1mtsmz6.qnno++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:107:12)
     at next (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/mibto_angular-compilers/.0.3.4.1i9jtu1.vtaoi++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.Angular_Compilers.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/angular-typescript-compiler/node_modules/browser-resolve/index.js:98:12)
     at load_shims (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/mibto_angular-compilers/.0.3.4.1i9jtu1.vtaoi++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.Angular_Compilers.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/angular-typescript-compiler/node_modules/browser-resolve/index.js:116:7)
     at resolve (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/mibto_angular-compilers/.0.3.4.1i9jtu1.vtaoi++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.Angular_Compilers.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/angular-typescript-compiler/node_modules/browser-resolve/index.js:236:5)
     at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/mibto_angular-compilers/.0.3.4.1i9jtu1.vtaoi++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.Angular_Compilers.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/angular-typescript-compiler/node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-resolve/dist/rollup-plugin-node-resolve.cjs.js:66:5
     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
     at Object.resolveId$1 [as resolveId] (/home/meteor/.meteor/packages/mibto_angular-compilers/.0.3.4.1i9jtu1.vtaoi++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.Angular_Compilers.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/angular-typescript-compiler/node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-resolve/dist/rollup-plugin-node-resolve.cjs.js:63:11)
     at resolveId (packages/angular-typescript-compiler/rollup.js:52:26)
     at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/mibto_angular-compilers/.0.3.4.1i9jtu1.vtaoi++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/plugin.Angular_Compilers.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/angular-typescript-compiler/node_modules/rollup/src/utils/first.js:8:31
     at /home/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.9.0.1mtsmz6.qnno++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:43:40 {
   code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE'
 }
```

I'm running following command to build:

```
METEOR_DISABLE_OPTIMISTIC_CACHING=1 ROLLUP=1 AOT=1 BABEL_CACHE_DIR=/tmp meteor build ../output
```

without `rollup` it works, and it also worked before Meteor 1.9

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: what do you need rollup for?

Comment: i found this here:
https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/tree/master/atmosphere-packages/angular-compilers#tree-shaking-mode-disabled-by-default-in-production

Comment: Given that that source is two years old, my guess would be that those mechanism have not been updated to keep up with changes in meteor. However, if it's working without rollup, then why not just leave it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think rollup=1 has ever worked properly in the angular-meteor compilers. I vaguely remember ardatan mentioning it in a github issue but can’t locate the exact one. The documentation still states it as an option but I think you should forget about it unless you want to fix the specific compiler issue.

Meteor 1.9 is a big upgrade as it uses node 12 so I would not be surprised if this has introduced an issue in the angular compilers package. It probably needs a few tweaks to bring it up to date.

Comment: this rings true for meteor 1.10 also and even truer if your trying to upgrade to angular 9,